# Element's name property is invisible to querySelectorAll and doesn't appear in its HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom, selectors-api

I want to select all list items with the name `'viewer'`.

This returns an empty `NodeList`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[name="viewer"]');
```

But this returns an array containing the correct items:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('li')].filter(({ name }) => name == 'viewer');
```

The list items were created like this:

```js
const listItem = document.createElement('li');
listItem.name = 'viewer';
listItem.id = 'viewer-1337';
```

When I inspect them in the console, I see their `id` in their HTML but not their `name`.  For example

```html
<li id="viewer-1337">foo</li>
```

It seems they do have the `name` property set, but it's not accessible via `document.querySelectorAll` or visible in their HTML.

Why not?

```js
const names = ['foo', 'bar'];
names.forEach(name => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.id = 'viewer-' + name;
  li.name = 'viewer';
  li.innerHTML = name;
  const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
  ul.appendChild(li);
});

const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('[name="viewer"]');
console.log([...nodeList]);

const array = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')].filter(({ name }) => name == 'viewer');
console.log(array);
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: As you’re creating the elements it seems worth asking if you’re trying to find them in the script before, or after, you’ve created them? It’s worth noting that `<li>` elements don’t have typically have a `name` property, though since you’ve assigned that property it should still work.

Comment: I added a Stack Snippet illustrating the problem.

Comment: There is no `name` attribute on `<li>` elements, setting the property doesn’t create the similarly-named attribute.

Comment: I agree with the comment about `<li>` not usually having a `name`.  Why not use a custom attribute called `data-myid` or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is occurring because the `name` attribute is [reserved](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name):

> name gets or sets the name property of an element in the DOM. It only applies to the following elements: `<a>, <applet>, <button>, <form>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <map>, <meta>, <object>, <param>, <select>, and <textarea>.`

When you set the `name` property of an element which is *not* one of those types, the element will *not* receive that value as an attribute value. It'll still be put onto the `name` property of the JavaScript object, but it won't be put into the attribute.

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
console.log(div.attributes.length);
div.name = 'foo';
console.log(div.attributes.length);
console.log(div.hasOwnProperty('name'));
```

So the query string `[name="viewer"]` does not select the elements (because they do not have the `name` attribute), but `[...document.querySelectorAll('li')].filter(({ name }) => name == 'viewer')` works because the `filter` callback is successfully retrieving the `name` property from the JavaScript representation of the element.

You can fix it by putting it into the dataset instead:

```js
const names = ['foo', 'bar'];
names.forEach(name => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.id = 'viewer-' + name;
  li.dataset.name = 'viewer';
  li.innerHTML = name;
  const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
  ul.appendChild(li);
});

const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-name="viewer"]');
console.log(nodeList.length);
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

As `li` elements don't have `name` attributes you cannot use a CSS selector to look for one. Just use a `data-name` attribute instead. It works as intended, see below:

```js
const names = ['foo', 'bar'];
names.forEach(name => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.id = 'viewer-' + name;
  li.dataset.name = 'viewer';
  li.innerHTML = name;
  const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
  ul.appendChild(li);
});

const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-name=viewer]');
console.log(nodeList);

const array = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')].filter(({ name }) => name == 'viewer');
console.log(array);
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Yeah, just noticed @certainperformance out-performed me again by 6 minutes ... ;-)